# Transferring probability histogram into a Beta distribution and adding this to an empty matrix

Tags: matrix, optimization, probability, beta-distribution

I have the following info for when a person can get infected:

```
age <- c(15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21)
probabilityofinfection <- c(0.0010169, 0.054234662, 0.236308169, 0.419834391, 0.239213597, 0.047455329, 0.001936952)
sum(getinfected) #adds up to 1
```

How do I put this into an rbeta distribution by using optimisation to get the shape parameters? And how do I add this to an empty matrix (500 rows, 10 columns) in a binomial fashion (i.e. infected= 1, uninfected=0). Thanks

Comment: In general, deriving distribution parameters from a histogram like that is an interesting optimization problem which requires some calculations a little beyond the scope of deriving parameters from an ordinary sample. However, you can get pretty close by constructing an approximate data sample from the histogram, and then deriving parameters from that using whatever is the standard approach for the distribution in question. In this case, the approximate sample would have, let's say 1000 elements, with 1 instance of 15, 54 instances of 16, 236 instances of 17, ..., 2 instances of 21.